# How do i pass a variable as wchat_t** from a std::wstring in c++

Tags: c++11, std, visual-studio-2019, wstring

I am using VS 2019 and the C++ Language Standard is set to Default which I assume is C++ 11?

I have the following constructor of a class in a header file:

```
input_parser(int& argc, wchar_t** argv)
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        this->tokens_.emplace_back(argv[i]);
    }
};
```

To call the methods argv parameter I am creating an array of wchar_t in the following manner:

```
std::wstring command_line = L"-m \"F-14RHV\" -s \"BIT|Flir\" -d";
auto buffer = new wchar_t[command_line.length() + 1];
wcsncpy_s(buffer, command_line.length()+1, command_line.c_str(), command_line.length() + 1);
const auto inputs = input_parser(argc, &buffer);
delete[] buffer;
```

Inside the constructor the first pass when `argc == 0` is fine but I get an access violation when `argc == 1`.

Comment: You can't. Not directly anyway. Instead you need to come up with a way to split the `command_line` string at a separator (space in your case) and create an array of `wchar_t` pointers that you pass to the `input_parser` function.

Comment: Also be careful with those double-quotes inside the string you attempt to initialize `command_line` with.

Comment: I should have escaped those but I was only showing the string that was being passed which in Visual Studio unescaped them. Why is it not possible to do this? I went ahead and escaped the double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so [some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) was correct and here is how I have to do it after I figure out how to split the string by spaces!

Here is the final answer:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

std::wstring text = L"-m \"F-14RHV\" -s \"BIT|Flir\" -d";
std::wistringstream iss(text);
std::vector<std::wstring> results((std::istream_iterator<std::wstring, wchar_t>(iss)),
std::istream_iterator<std::wstring, wchar_t>());
```

Using a vector is going to make this process MUCH easier. I will probably change the other side to use a vector now.

Thanks for the help.